# Printing flyer design on home printer turns out muddy

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cmyk, posters, advertising

I designed a flyer in Photoshop, consisting of bright text over a dark stock image, and tried to print it on my own printer to get some idea of what it would look like when professional printed. However, when printed the dark background of the stock image can only be described as very muddy, to the point of being barely visible, even while the text itself stands out fine.

The Photoshop document is CMYK and was exported to PDF for printing, and looking at the specs for the [printer](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/printers/inkjet-printers/for-home/expression-home-xp-315#specifications), it *seems* to support CMYK, so it doesn't seem that a conversion from RGB is happening here.

**Is this a design problem, and therefore something that's likely to crop up when taking the design to the printer, or something else?**

Comment: What kind of printer do you have? Inkjet or laser?

Comment: @curious [This](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/printers/inkjet-printers/for-home/expression-home-xp-315#specifications) is the printer, I'm pretty sure it's an inkjet, but my confusion about this problem comes from the fact that it seems to support CMYK.

Comment: what type of paper did you print on? Laser typically outputs mediocre color but it seems to be an inkjet. Could also be a paper thing.

Comment: It was standard printing paper, nothing special. Could that really be the cause for such a drastic loss in quality on the background in particular?

Comment: Home/consumer grade inkjet printers rarely support printing of CMYK files, even though the inks are CMYK. Try an RGB image with an sRGB colour profile instead.

Comment: @BillyKerr When you say an RGB image do you mean the stock image or the file itself?

Comment: I agree with @BillyKerr send RGB data... always best for end use printers.. ESPECIALLY multi-function printers. Those *never* support CMYK data.

Comment: @Scott I've read a lot of your posts on this topic on this Stack site, but my confusion stems from the fact that, as per the specs linked to for my printer, it *does* seem to support CMYK.

Comment: I read the spec's ... where are you seeing CMYk support? I found *nothing* about print technologies used. Typically it's PCL or CUPS.... If you are seeing "colors" that's **not** the same as *support* for CMYK. I have an Epson multifunction which is markable higher quality than this one and it does *not* support CMYK data. I can not fathom that the XP-315 would.

Comment: @Scott Fair enough, I was assuming that the colors section meant the printer supported CMYK. So am I to assume that the answer to this question is that it is the fault of my own printer, and as long as I am working in CMYK while designing it, the flyer should look more or less as intended when printed by  professional printers, with the stock image background showing through as expected?

Comment: Theoretically yes, if you have a well calibrated system and are using correct color profiles. If you want or need a color proof, you can get that from a commercial printer *before* the job is run (but it does cost).